# How to link the unlinked files?

Tags: files, filesystems, data-recovery

When you `rm` a file it will call unlink(), and unlink() will remove the file from the Directory entry and its inode is freed. But, the actual content of the file is still in the disk.

Is there any way to get back the file again i.e add it back to directory entry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process will depend on what type of files you have (image, text file, etc.) and what file system is in use. [This page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_Recovery) of the Arch Wiki has some good places to start. It specifically mentions Foremost, Extundelete, Testdisk, and PhotoRec as some programs to look at.

One method mentioned that may be of interest to you is basically getting all raw text from the drive, and then using `grep` to find a the data from a text file.

```
# strings /dev/sdXN > BigStringsFile
```

Look for the unique string and send output to a file.

```
$ grep -i -200 "Unique string in text file" BigStringsFile > GrepOutputFile
```

The `-200` outputs 200 lines before and after the string it finds, which you can adjust to cover the whole text file.

As always when messing with your data, it is important to back up important data and/or work on an unimportant copy. Among other reasons, these tools can write results to disk, so they could overwrite what you are trying to restore.

Comment: Well this works fine with text files but Can you please explain the     how to recover the image and other media files...?

Comment: I mentioned a few programs there, one of which (PhotoRec) is specifically for images.